# How to clear out search box value in one component when another component is called?

Tags: angular

I have a search bar in the header of my application , when i search anything and press enter a grid opens in the page .

But when I navigate to a different page , I want the search bar input to be cleared . Currently the searched input stays as it is .

As the search bar is in header component , and the page is another component , I am having issues clearing the search box value on page navigations .

Can anyone help me with the approach ?

Comment: We need to see your code to help you as the best. From what you're saying, you can listen to router events. When it change, you reset the searchbar input. But you should provide your code first

Comment: please make a sample in https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply listen to your routerEvents and at any navigationEnd you can clear the input value.